# POST URL as Data with cURL to Rest Services

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl, urlencode

I tried to POST some data to Rest API but I am getting failure messages. I tried some different ways to do but I can not do that. I have a PHP Client which uses cURL and Codeigniter Rest Service.

When I want to POST data array to REST, there is no problem. System uses urlencode and urldecode. But when I post URL data like **website => 'http://abc.com'**, it gives error like "Object not found". How can I post URL's to the Server? Is there a way or ways to POST Data without encode-decode? Data Array is given below.

```
  $data = array('id' => urlencode('12'),
        'name' => urlencode('Test'),
        'website' => urlencode('http://www.test.com'));
```

The second question is, When i POST data as Array, i can not get this Array.

`$array = $this->get('parameters');` not working.

```
$data = array('parameters' => array('id' => urlencode('12'),
            'name' => urlencode('Test'),
            'website' => urlencode('http://www.test.com')));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this as a simplest idea getting those value below your 
`$array = $this->get('parameters');` ..

is

`$array = array('parameters'=> $data);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use serialize() and unserialize() functions of php